# Delete button is not able to delete buttons. It is responsive in the console but nothing else

Tags: javascript, delete-row

i'm having trouble using my delete button with my code. Instead of deleting an object, it creates a new one. code is under render items function. i've tried several things but it seems like my biggest problem is the placement of the rederItems function in the if statement. I also added the html to show you how that looks like too. Thanks!

```js
//  selectors 
var nameOfItem = document.getElementById("nameOfItem");
var saveOfItem = document.getElementById("nameOfItem");

var shoppingList = document.getElementById("shoppingListContainer");

var nameArray = ["tea","bread","rice"]
// var nameArray = []
var setCart = [];
var getIngredientsForCart = localStorage.getItem
var emptyListText = document.getElementById("emptyList")
var removeButton = document.getElementById('removeItem');
var saveItems = document.getElementById("saveItems");
var cart = document.getElementById("shoppingListContainer")

cart.style.visibility = 'hidden';
saveItems.style.visibility = 'hidden'

saveItems.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log('saved')
    setCart.push(entry);
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(newArray));
});


/*

<li class="list-group-item" id="numberOfItems">1</li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="nameOfItem"></li>
            <li class="list-group-item" id="removeItem"></li>

*/



// get from local storage
// var food = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Ingredients"))
// console.log(food)
// nameArray = food



// --------------------------------
// render Item function
// --------------------------------
function renderItems() {
    for (i = 0; i < nameArray.length; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement("div");
        row.setAttribute("class", "row");


        var col2 = document.createElement("div");
        var col3 = document.createElement("div");


        col2.setAttribute("class", "col-8 item-name");
        col3.setAttribute("class", "col-2 item-delete");

        var newButton = document.createElement('button');
        newButton.textContent = 'Delete';
        newButton.setAttribute("data-item-idx", i);
        newButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
            console.log(event.target.dataset.itemIdx)
            var selectedItem = parseInt(event.target.dataset.itemIdx);
            
            
            if(nameArray.splice(selectedItem, 1)){
                console.log(nameArray)
                renderItems()
            }
        })
        

        col2.textContent = nameArray[i];
        col3.appendChild(newButton);


        row.appendChild(col2);
        row.appendChild(col3);

        shoppingList.appendChild(row);
    }
}


// --------------------------------
// shopping Cart function
// --------------------------------
function shoppingCart() {
    emptyListText.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    cart.style.visibility = 'visible';
    saveItems.style.visibility = 'visible'
    renderItems()
}



   


// execute Function
shoppingCart()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />

    <title>Meal Plan</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/shoppinglist.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Shopping List</h1>
        <a href="../../index.html">search recipes</a>
    </div>
    <h1 id="emptyList">Cart is Empty :(</h1>
    <section id="shoppingListContainer" class="container">


    </section>
    <button id="saveItems">Save Items</button>
</body>
<!-- <script src="/projects/mealPlan/assets/js/script.js"></script> -->
<script src="../js/shoppingList.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `renderItems()` again on delete but you are never actually clearing the existing rendered html.

Simply adding `shoppingList.innerHTML = "";` to the start of the `renderItems()` function will clear the html each time render runs.